# Unity camera follows player rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, position, transform, quaternions

I want my camera to follow the player rotation but the camera should always have an angle to the player.
I have this:

```
transform.rotation = player.transform.rotation;
```

But now the Camera looks straight at the player and not at an angle from above. How can I add my wanted angle to the rotation?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
transform.rotation = player.transform.rotation + wantedAngle;
```

Comment: my wanted angle change over time because when I rotate the player the camera angle changes so this doesn't work

Comment: Maybe you were mistaken? Maybe you actually DON'T want your camera follow the player rotation? Try:

             transform.rotation = wantedAngle;

Comment: `Quaternion`s have to be combined using a multiplication `*` instead of an addition `+` !

Answer (score 0):

I had to use

```
 transform.rotation = player.transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(45,0,0);
```